# Is storing a reference of an inner class in a variable that is only going to be used locally (e.g. within a function) wasteful of memory?

Tags: design, programming-practices

For example

```
class A 
{
    public int data1 {get; set;}
    public int data2 {get; set;}
}
class B 
{
    public A objectA;
}
class C
{
    public B objectB;
}
class D
{
    public C objectC
}
class E
{
    public D objectD;
}

class Caller
{
    public void foo(E input)
    {
        var bar = input.objectD.objectC.objectB.objectA;

        // code that looks nice
        if (bar.data1 == 1)
        {
            // do something
        }

        // code that looks nice again
        if (bar.data2 == 2)
        {
            // do something again
        }

        // but why?
        if (input.objectD.objectC.objectB.objectA.data1 == 0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Just for the sake of getting my point across, here is an example call for a property that is nested deep within an inner class. Surely a class that requires such a deep call to get into data requires refactoring. But as an example of what I'm trying to say consider class E who has a property of class D which references down to other class up to class A which holds the data we need.

To avoid typing a long winded call to objectA coming from class E, I store objectA into a variable. If the object is only to be used within the scope of a few lines would it be a waste of memory? Aside from making it easier to type, readable, or maybe even maintainable; what other merits are there?

Comment: I think you'll find that, if you write classes that solve an actual problem, a better class design will become readily apparent.  The amount of memory used is an insignificant problem compared to the maintenance nightmare that this arrangement will cause.

Comment: It is not wasted: it is recycled as soon as the function returns. Memory waste occurs when one doesn't `free()` a memory block obtained with `malloc()`

Comment: Your question title says "used once", but your example uses the local variable twice.

Comment: You're right. Let me rephrase it to a better one. Apologies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use local variables as much as you like.  They are super cheap (basically totally free) and offer an opportunity to document (by choosing a meaningful name) what you are doing.

Personally, I like local variables, as I find they increase readability and tend to facilitate debugging — you can quickly see their values during single stepping, and when exceptions happen, shorter expressions setting local variables help narrow them down.

However, some find this highly annoying and prefer to repeat expressions rather than collect information in local variables.  They might say, why are you capturing this value in a local variable -- are you expecting it to change (and want to work only with the original value)??

There is sometimes merit to these arguments, but I tend to disagree with them.  When I see repeated uses of complex expressions, I ask the same question from another orientation: why did the programmer keep repeating the same expression -- are they expecting it to change (and want to work each time with the new value)??

Many algorithms won't work if certain values change within a few lines of code; though fortunately, it turns out that they typically don't so this isn't as big a problem as we might make out, and perhaps it is more a matter of style, I think, as to use of local variables vs. repeating yourself.

(Please note that the above advocates use of local variables as temporaries, but not additional fields as temporaries.)

Comment: `local variables as temporaries, but additional fields as temporaries`. Is that intended? Sounds like there is a `not` missing somewhere, or maybe `non-temporaries`?

Comment: @RaimundKrämer, yes, thx.

Comment: Correct answer, but way way too long.

Answer (score 1):

Yes...No...Maybe.
In general, you won't know if it's wasted memory.

Should you care? No. The compiler deals with this. Let the compiler do their job.

What you should care about is readability AND about code that keeps doing the same.

Using vars like that can increase readability by getting rid of silly long lines of code.

However the code needs to keep doing the same, there's at least 2 things which need care:
You have to make absolutely sure that you are storing a reference and not a copy in your variable, this is a source of many bugs.
Also you need to make sure that reading a.b.c.d.e.f doesn't have side-effects somewhere down the chain.
Properties can have side-effects just by reading them.

Comment: "*Properties can have side-effects just by reading them*". And anyone writing properties that do that should be publicly flogged using a copy of "Clean Code" and banned from touching a computer for six months. It's the only way they'll learn! :)

Answer (score 0):

> If the object is only to be used within the scope of a few lines would
>   it be a waste of memory?

It's difficult to answer this perfectly precisely but I'm going with just "no" (I'm not the type of person to rely on for technical precision). I think it is better to think of it as just "no". There might be some really obscure case where this doesn't hold true, but I see that as best discovered in a profiling session when analyzing the resulting disassembly, and even then I'd still say to believe the answer is "no" and just pass that off as an oddity. :-D

Because we already have a fixed amount of really fast memory set aside in registers. Compilers generally allocate these local variables into registers. And the variable doesn't necessarily take "more register memory" because the result of the expression it stored would likewise generally have to be moved to a register before any instructions can be executed on it.

And sometimes the results are spilled to the stack, but the stack is preallocated memory which gets popped when the analogical variable goes out of scope (or when the expression is no longer used), and again the same would apply for the results of the expression the variable stores. So compared to the expression itself, the practical way to think of it from a memory standpoint is that it's absolutely free of charge.

> Aside from making it easier to type, readable, or maybe even
>   maintainable; what other merits are there?

If your compiler is not so smart, capturing the results of an expression to a variable might help it allocate registers more effectively and avoid repeating the same instructions involved to evaluate the expression. However, that's a generally horrible reason to use more variables for a basic expression because first of all compilers are typically very smart, and secondly it's not very productive to be trying to help compilers perform register allocation and instruction selection. You want to go with the flow of the optimizer and let it help you out, not try to defeat it and step on its toes, or else you might as well write code in assembly.

So I think you listed most of the merits already. I wanted to jump in here because it's not so uncommon that I encounter people who are afraid to store a local variable out of fear that it has some kind of memory/performance hit, and that fear could become very counter-productive. It almost certainly doesn't, and in some obscure hypothetical case, may actually have the opposite effect -- but again you shouldn't use local variables with the intention of trying to help optimizers as opposed to the good reasons you listed like readability and maintainability. I just point this out because the intuition that local variables cost something is so potentially wrong because the same things you want to analogically store to the local variable have to be moved/loaded to a register anyway and are susceptible to the same stack spills.

Personally I like when people capture the results of a lengthy expression to a local variable (or ideally a named constant if it cannot change from that point on), since it's not only shortening the amount of code I have to read, but also communicating that everything that references it from that point on is accessing the same thing at a glance. And naturally tying to the maintainable example, if the assumption that everything from that point on accesses the same result, it gives you one line of code to change if the result needs to change as opposed to many.